# Angular material table doesn't filter data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to implement filteridn using material-table.
My code:

***Host.ts***

```
    export class HostIndexComponent implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns: string[] = [
      'Hostname',
      'HostGroup',
      'LAN IP',
      'WAN IP',
      'LAN IF',
      'WAN IF'
    ];
            
   hosts: Host[] = [];
   public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Host>();

  constructor(public hostService: HostService) {
   }
    

  ngOnInit() {
    this.hostService.getAll().subscribe((data: Host[])=>{
      this.dataSource.data =  data;
   })
  }


  public doFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    console.log(this.dataSource.data);    
  }
```

***Host.html***

```
   <mat-form-field>
     <input matInput  (keyup)="doFilter($event)" placeholder="Filter"> 
   </mat-form-field>
  </div> 
   
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8"> 
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let host">{{ host[column] }}</td>
     </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let hostrow; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>                 
 </table>
```

When i open the form i don't see data in web console,but i see all data (without filtering) when i typing in filter input. But anyway no any data in table.
Where i'm wrong?

***UPD:***
I was mistaked - filtered values are visible in web console , so filtering seems ok, but data doesn't appear in table

Answer (score 1):

The "datasource" of a mat-table can be an array or a MatTableDataSource. Only if is a MatTableDataSource you get all the "properties" of them, filter, sort, pagination...

So create the mattabledataSource with your array:

```
   this.hostService.getAll().subscribe((data: Host[])=>{
      this.dataSource.data =  new MatTableDataSource(data);
   })
```